# wininet-asyncrhonous HTTP post c++

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I am doing a POST with a query string followed by a file.I have heavily borrowed from MS sample.

```
    ZeroMemory(&BuffersIn, sizeof(INTERNET_BUFFERS));
    BuffersIn.dwStructSize = sizeof(INTERNET_BUFFERS);
    BuffersIn.lpvBuffer =(LPVOID)querystring.c_str();
    BuffersIn.dwBufferLength =querystring.size();
    buffersIn.dwBufferTotal = ReqContext->FileSize+BuffersIn.dwBufferLength;
```

followed by

```
     Success = HttpSendRequestEx(ReqContext->RequestHandle,
                            &BuffersIn,
                            NULL,                 
                            0,                    
                            (DWORD_PTR)ReqContext);
```

InternetWriteFile follows later in an asyncrhonous manneras the inputfile is read asynchronously with readfile..

am I setting buffers and lengths correctly?my objective is to send a query string up front for authentication followed by the file to be uploaded. is this the right way to do what I wanted?

Comment: Have you considered using more straightforward WinHTTP instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384081(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A query string is part of the URL itself, in the portion following the `?` character, eg: `http://domain/path?query_string_goes_here`. You don't send a query string as separate POST data.

Comment: Also, read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa384318.aspx) more carefully: "`HttpSendRequestEx` performs both the send and the receive for the response. **This does not allow the application to send any extra data beyond the single buffer that was passed to `HttpSendRequestEx`. Callers that need to send extra data beyond what is normally passed to `HttpSendRequestEx` can do so by calling `HttpSendRequest` instead. After the call to `HttpSendRequestEx`, send the remaining data by calling `InternetWriteFile`**. Finally, follow up with a call to HttpEndRequest."

Comment: There is a typo in the documentation. "After the call to `HttpSendRequestEx`, send the remaining data by calling `InternetWriteFile`" should say `HttpSendRequest` instead of `HttpSendRequestEx`.

Comment: The requirement is specifically wininet...@remy,i am returning to winnet after my very first job 12 years ago and not in great touch:)...does it mean I just concatenate the query string to the root url and use the full string in hostname parameter  of Internetconnect or HttpOpen request? what are the ways of passing the query string in wininet?